# kartik DynaGrid select2 filter not render

Tags: yii2, jquery-select2, yii2-dynagrid

my setup column using kartik DynaGrid Widget to display data on yii2. but filter (FILTER_SELECT2) not render on my table. Can someone help me? Please.

```
    'class' => 'kartik\grid\DataColumn',
    'attribute' => 'city_id',
    'label' => 'City',
    'hAlign' => 'center',
    'vAlign' => 'middle',
    'width' => '70px',
    'filterType' => GridView::FILTER_SELECT2,
    'filter' => [
       1 => 'filter 1',
       2 => 'filter 2',
    ],
    'format' => 'html',
    'value' => function($data){
        $cities = \app\models\City::getData();
        if(isset($cities[$data->city_id])){
            return $cities[$data->city_id];
        }

        return $data->city_id;

    }
```

Answer (score 0):

Post your grid config. Maybe you turn off filter in config. Default config is this

```
 ....
    'gridOptions'=>[
            'dataProvider'=>$dataProvider,
            'filterModel'=>$searchModel,
            ....
    ],
```